# Identifiable protocol in Swift: class vs struct

Tags: swift, identifiable

I'm using Swift 5.3

Trying to understand why when I declare this construction

```
final class MyActivity: Identifiable {
    public let iHaveNoId: String = ""
}
```

it compiles without any errors (even if I don't have "id" field implemented), while for struct

```
struct MyActivity: Identifiable {
    public let iHaveNoId: String = ""
}
```

I get an error (as expected) - **Type 'MyActivity' does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'**

Moreover, if I copy Identifiable source code and rename it to my own name, e.g.

```
public protocol MyIdentifiable {
    associatedtype ID : Hashable
    var id: Self.ID { get }
}
```

then both struct and class implementing MyIdentifiable protocol will fail with a proper error **Type 'MyActivity' does not conform to protocol 'MytIdentifiable'**

I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable/3285392-id) of `Identifiable` states, it does provide a default implementation for `id` for class types. However, there is no default implementation for `struct`s, hence you need to add the property manually.

Comment: Found it few minutes before you posted your answer, but documentation was not explicit about no default implementation for struct. Thank you.

Comment: @interrupt Yes it was: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable/3285392-id "The stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
Available when Self conforms to AnyObject."

Comment: how come your `MyIdentifiable` also fails for class then, if it also has a default for class?

Comment: @qkhhly that's not "my" `MyIdentifiable` and it also has no default implementation in the question.